# Force refresh access token in datasource settings

Tags: sql-server, spring, spring-boot, azure, azure-active-directory

I have a problem, and it is that the configuration of my datasource that attacks SQL Server has an access token, but the access token expires after a few hours.
When I make a query after twelve hours, and the token has expired, an error appears in the service and I have to restart the service so that it calculates a new token and configures it in the new datasource.
I refer to this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/connecting-using-azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-2017#connecting-using -access-token
But instead of using a SQLServerDataSource I have used a HikariDataSource

```
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        HikariConfig config = hikariConfig();
        IAuthenticationResult result = acquireToken(spn, url, clientId, clientSecret);
        String accessToken = result.accessToken();
        config.getDataSourceProperties().setProperty("accessToken", accessToken);
        return new HikariDataSource(config);
    }
```

Acquiere token is like than this articles:

https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-java
https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-java/blob/dev/src/samples/confidential-client/ClientCredentialGrant.java

I have always the same problem:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: SqlserverCP - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30000ms.

Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user '<token-identified principal>'. Token is expired. ClientConnectionId:xxxxx
```

**How can I refresh the token without restarting the service?**

Comment: All content on [so] should be in English; you need to translate your last statement.

Comment: @Larnu yes, sorry. I have already changed all the non-English text.